# Server not pointing to folder

Tags: asp.net

i have a website on server. It has a button which triggers the downloading of a file(.zip/.doc) from that server.
But it is not pointing to that folder/file. How to resolve this issue??

It fails at this particular file...

```
public static bool ResponseFile(HttpRequest _Request, HttpResponse _Response, string _fileName, string _fullPath, long _speed){
FileStream myFile = new FileStream(_fullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
}
```

Comment: Even we cannot resove this issue without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tried your code but this seems to work for me. you can make the rest dynamic.

```
string FileName = "test.zip";
string PathFile = "C:\project\download\test.zip";
var fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(PathFile);
Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename=\"{0}\"", FileName));
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString());
Response.WriteFile(PathFile);
Response.End();
```

Comment: my application can download file available on local system when runing on localhost...but the same application when uploaded on server..it didnt work...so i guess coding is not a issue

Comment: pop up blocker or something? or browser compatability with code. might be the difference.

Comment: it used to work earlier...suddenly stopped...tried in all the major browser...no popup blocks..